# Не срабатывает ng-repeat (AngularJS)

Tags: angularjs, ng-repeat

Браузер самостоятельно загоняет ng-repeat в коммент. 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не могу найти причину.
Вот код:

```
   <div class="container">
        <table>
            <tr ng-repeat="x in historyDataView">
                <td>{{$index + 1 }}</td>
                <td>{{x.Agent}}</td>
                <td>{{ x.BcustomerID }}</td>
                <td>{{ x.EcustomerAddressCity }}</td>
                <td>{{ x.EcustomerAddressCountry }}</td>
                <td>{{ x.EcustomerAddressState }}</td>
                <td>{{ x.EcustomerAddressStreet }}</td>
                <td>{{ x.EcustomerAddressZip }}</td>
                <td>{{ x.EcustomerEmail }}</td>
                <td>{{ x.EcustomerName }}</td>
                <td>{{ x.EcustomerPhoneNum }}</td>
                <td>{{ x.OrderDateAdded }}</td>
                <td>{{ x.OrderStatus }}</td>
                <td>{{ x.ShippingPrice }}</td>
                <td>{{ x.ShippingType }}</td>
                <td>{{ x.order_id }}</td>
                <td>{{ x.products }}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
```

Код app.js:

```
.then(function successCallback(response) {
            $scope.resRealDate = response; 
           // console.log($scope.resRealDate);
            $scope.historyDataView =  $scope.resRealDate.data
            console.log($scope.historyDataView)
```

Данные получаю, все нормально. 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score -1):

$scope.historyDataView несуществует, его необходимо вернуть.

```
$scope.historyDataView = [];
.then(function successCallback(response) {
        $scope.resRealDate = response; 
       // console.log($scope.resRealDate);
        $scope.historyDataView =  $scope.resRealDate.data;
        return $scope.historyDataView;
});
```